# editing WordPress Theme with content embedded in PHP script

Tags: php, wordpress, web, editor, themes

I am trying to redo my homepage of my website which is a WordPress website. The homepage is hardcoded in PHP, and I would like to figure out how to

1. Replace some of the image files
2. Edit the text under those image files

I have redesigned the (4) image files I want to update the site with, but I don't know where in the script to paste the name of those files. There are tones of file slike index.php, theme,php, and I would figure that under these I would see "front_forecast.png" somewhere where I could erase that and type in the image file name I want there instead, but I haven't had success.

Comment: you would help yourself by learning wp theme setup, check [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). maybe home.php or index.php in active theme directory

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be a bit hard to help you without seeing some code, your current site, or even knowing what your theme is. As gwillie said though, it might be best to go back to basics first.

From a template pov, I have always found this diagram helpful in understanding how WordPress uses its templates to output content (source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Visual_Overview):

[image: WordPress Template Hierarchy]